# Reinstalling network manager & icon issues

Tags: network-manager, icons, system-tray, kde4, debootstrap

I just updated to ubuntu 14.04 LTE and network manager is giving me a question mark in my system tray even though I can connect to the internet.  This really irritates me.

I tried hiding network manager in system and and making it reappear to see if it would reset but it hasn't.  I also tried switching themes and rebooting system to see if it would reset icons, but this doesn't work either...

I'm out of ideas so I was thinking of reinstalling network manager... My question:  If I reinstall or remove network manager, can my computer still connect to the internet or not?

I dont want to uninstall it and then not have internet to redownload it again.  I'd appreciate some info on the proper procedure for this.

Can I just do `sudo aptitude reinstall network-manager`?

Thanks.

[image]

### EDIT

I also deleted the cache folder (`/var/tmp/kdecache-$USER/`) and rebooted my system.  This also did not work.

Moreover, if I click on network manager icon in system tray, there's an icon in the middle with bars which is grayed out. Does anyone know what that means?  I can't click on it for some reason...

[image]

Do you have to have `network-manager` package to have internet working?  I wanted to try and uninstall/reinstall it but wasn't sure if I would be able to if I did as I thought it might be required for internet to work.

Comment: Actually that `?` is not in the original icon, it is just an overlay added by the applet. like in case of network errors ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue and learned a few things:

`network-manager` package manages all connections the internet (ethernet, wifi, etc).  You can use network manager or configure internet connection using `/etc/network/interfaces` file.  I did the latter which is why I had internet, but did not configure network manager.

All I did was set `/etc/network/interfaces` to the following:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Then in network manager, add the ethernet connection to the list of active devices!